# WInRT disable listview animation when reordering items

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

How do you guys remove/disable animation when moving an item in ListView?

ListView's source is binded from my ModelView using ObservableCollection. When I try to .Move an item from oldIndex to newIndex, the lists animates as if it refreshes everything.

How do I turn this off?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way you could do is by removing `ItemContainerTransitions` from `ListView`'s style.

In Document Outline, edit `ListView`'s style

[image]

In generated style, find `ItemContainerTransitions` setter and remove it.

[image]

Comment: I was expecting removing ReorderThemeTransition could solve it but instead the ContentThemeTransition.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
        <ListView ......
                  Transitions="{x:Null}"
                  ItemContainerTransitions="{x:Null}"/>
```

This gonna disable all you transition animations. Works with UWP as well.

Comment: This is a way better solution than in the answer above.